How to proof that (Tf)(x) is bounded linear operator
show that $(Tf)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\pi(x^2+y^2)}f(y)dy$ is bounded linear operator on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, for $1\le p<\infty$.
I could prove that, it is linear and know that I most prove that $\parallel (Tf) (x)\parallel_p\le M \parallel f(x)\parallel_p$ but I don’t have an idea. Thanks for your helping.

Let $\exp_a : x \to e^{-a \pi x^2}$ be defined on $\mathbb{R}$. This function is $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for all $1 \leqslant p \leqslant \infty$ and we can write $e^{-\pi(x^2+y^2)} = \exp_1(x) \times \exp_1(y)$.
Suppose $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $1 \leqslant p < \infty$ and let $q$ be the Holder conjugate of $p$.
Then $\displaystyle \Vert (Tf) (x) \Vert_p^p = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left| \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\pi(x^2+y^2)} f(y) dy \right|^p dx \leqslant  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp_p(x) \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp_1(y) |f(y)| dy \right)^p dx \leqslant$
$\displaystyle  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp_p(x) \Big( \Vert \exp_1 \Vert_q \cdot \Vert f \Vert_p \Big)^p dx=  \Vert \exp_1 \Vert_q^p \cdot \Vert f \Vert_p^p \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp_p(x) dx =$
$\displaystyle \Vert \exp_1 \Vert_q^p \cdot \Vert f \Vert_p^p \cdot \Vert \exp_1 \Vert_p^p $
In the first inequality, we use the fact that the absolute value of the integral is less than the integral of the absolute value.
In the second inequality, we use Holder for the interior integral.
So we get $\displaystyle \Vert (Tf) \Vert_p \leqslant \Vert \exp_1 \Vert_q  \cdot \Vert \exp_1 \Vert_p \cdot  \Vert f \Vert_p = M \cdot  \Vert f \Vert_p$ for $M = \Vert \exp_1 \Vert_q  \cdot \Vert \exp_1 \Vert_p$

We have that
$$
(Tf)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\pi(x^2+y^2)}f(y)d\lambda(y)
= e^{-\pi x^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\pi(y^2)}f(y)d\lambda(y)
$$
Now define the measure $\lambda'$ on $\mathbb R$ by $\forall S\in \mathcal{B}:\quad \lambda'(S) = \int_S e^{-\pi(y^2)} d\lambda(y)$.
With this we now have:
$$
(Tf)(x) 
= e^{-\pi x^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)d\lambda'(y)
\le e^{-\pi x^2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(y)|d\lambda'(y)
= e^{-\pi x^2} \left(\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(y)|d\lambda'(y)\right)^p\right)^{1/p}
$$
Since $\lambda'(\mathbb R) = 1$, $\lambda'$ is a probability measure. And because $x^p$ for $p\ge 1$ is convex on $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$, we can use Jensen's inequality:
$$
\le e^{-\pi x^2} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(y)|^p d\lambda'(y)\right)^{1/p}
=e^{-\pi x^2} \|f\|_p
$$
Now all that's left is to put this into $\| Tf\|$:
$$
\| Tf\|
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\pi(x^2+y^2)}f(y)d\lambda(y)d\lambda(x) 
\le \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\pi x^2} \|f\|_p d\lambda(x)
= \|f\|_p \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\pi x^2}  d\lambda(x)
=\|f\|_p
$$
